# CodeIgniter: how to create common layout

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know that how to create a common layout for CodeIgniter framework and how to access it in controller.

I created some layout file, but I don't know that how to load files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <base href="<?php //echo base_url();   ?>" />

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" >

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <!--    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Blog </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('article/add'); ?>">Add Article</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>



                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>



                 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;">

            <!--container-->
            <?php  echo $content; ?>

        </div>  





        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    </body>
```

please help to me load another view files to this layout file.

Comment: you need to load view from controller as $this->load->view('yourviewname',$data) and you can test by calling controller

Answer (score 1):

First make a custom loader

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader{
      function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
      }

      function page($page, $vars=array(), $return=FALSE){
         $vars['page'] = $page;
         $ci = &get_instance();
         $ci->load->view('layout',$vars,$return);
      }
  }
```

save it into application/core/MY_Loader.php

Now in controller load page

```
       $this->load->page('page_name');
```

In View

```
 <div class="container">
    <?php $this->load->view($page) ?>
 </div>
```